# ItemCommand Event in inner updatepanel refreshes outer updatepanel content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have 2 `updatepanel`s in a webforms page with 2 nested `Repeater` controls. In the second (inner Repeater control) I have a `LinkButton` to do some events and calling the click event through the `OnItemCommand` method of the second Repeater.

This is my Example Asp.Net page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater2_ItemCommand">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblInsertedDate" class="text-muted" runat="server" Text=' <%# string.Format("{0: hh:mm tt}", Eval("Date")) %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFollow" runat="server" Text="Follow" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("BrokerId") %>' CommandName="Follow"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I click on the `LinkButton`, I can see the contents of the outer Repeater also gets XHRed when I inspect through browser's network Tab.

I don't want to update the contents of outer `updatepanel` when I click on the `linkbutton` inside. I want to change only text of the linkbutton with some server side function, so that the content download will be gets reduced.

Similar Question asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543567/updatepanel-with-updatemode-conditional-and-childrenastriggers-false-refreshed-b with no answer for it.

I tried to set `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and `ClientAsTriggers` as `false` to both the inner and outer updatepanels. However it's not working. Using .net version 4.51. Any workaround for this?